# NameError: name 'mark_safe' is not defined (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, nameerror

I have this code below in **"admin.py"**:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget

class CustomAdminFileWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        result = []
        if hasattr(value, "url"):
            result.append(
                f'''<a href="{value.url}" target="_blank">
                      <img 
                        src="{value.url}" alt="{value}" 
                        width="100" height="100"
                        style="object-fit: cover;"
                      />
                    </a>'''
            )
        result.append(super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer))
        return mark_safe("".join(result))
```

Then, I got this error below:

> NameError: name 'mark_safe' is not defined

So, I want to import **"mark_safe"** but I don't know where I can get the **"mark_safe"** from:

```py
from <I_do_not_know> import mark_safe
```

Where can I get **"mark_safe"** from?

Answer (score 3):

Import [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.safestring) from `django.utils.safestring` as shown below:

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```